# Flickr - Scribe Java - cannot use the demo to get the token

Tags: java, oauth, flickr, scribe

Using the sample code for Flickr on ScribeJava :

```
    final String apiKey = "xxx";
    final String apiSecret = "xx";
    final OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder(apiKey).apiSecret(apiSecret)
        .debug()
        .build(FlickrApi.instance(FlickrApi.FlickrPerm.DELETE));
    final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("=== Flickr's OAuth Workflow ===");
    System.out.println();
    // Obtain the Request Token
    System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
    final OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
```

I got an error page from Flickr and with debug, I got the following *error*
response status code: 411

What am I doing wrong? (last version of scribe-java 4.1.2)